# Visual Studio 2013, Windows Forms, won't build *.exe, errors CA0052 CA0055

Tags: winforms, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013

I am writing a Windows form application, I have around 20 or so elements, mostly text and combo boxes. Everything was working perfectly when I started getting the popup: "Unable to start program... The system cannot find the file specified" upon starting the debug. The code compiles without getting any error or warning. Code analysis gives me errors CA0052 and CA0055, which I couldn't get out much from. The file vc.nativecodeanalysis.all.xml contains a warning(edited a bit for clarity)

> warning C28204:  : Only one of this overload and the one at
>   (<no file>(0)) are annotated for *Param*(1): both or neither must
>   be annotated.

It points to just this line, in myform.h :

```
public ref class MyForm : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
```

If I just comment away another line here, no matter which one, the application will work again correctly:

```
private: System::Void State_SelectedIndexChanged(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
    label16->Visible = false;
    //objvalue->Visible = false;
    label17->Visible = false;
    result->Visible = false;        }
```

This is just where the issue first presented itself but I doubt the problem is here, I have more events like this, so I can "mix and match", but I can't find a single textbox or whatever that is the actual cause.

I have an int Main function, Windows (/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS) under Linker->Systems->Subsystems.

Don't know what to think about this, It's the first I'm dabbling with forms and everything was going pretty smooth, this is just a little utility I'm writing for a main project and was hoping to be done in little time since it's really pretty simple stuff. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to clean your code, by right click your solution in the solution explorer => clean, then debug

Comment: exact same behaviour sadly.